# ¿Cuantas veces se puede "conectar" de forma simultanea (al mismo tiempo) una Web (php) a un xml?

Tags: php, html5, xml, phpmyadmin

tengo entendido que a una base de datos (phpmyadmin) se pueden conectar varios usuarios de forma simultanea (al mismo tiempo) hasta 37 usuarios en algunos servidores, que se puede ampliar en algunos otros a 50 y también con un VPS se pueden hacer más conexiones simultaneas a PHPMYADMIN. ¿Cuantos usuarios de forma simultanea se pueden "conectar" de php a xml? ¿no tiene limite?
Ejemplo: 50 usuarios dan clic al mismo tiempo a un botón en PHP que se conecta a un XML ¿no tiene ningún problema? ¿y si ese xml se abre y se intenta modificar por los mismos 50 de forma simultanea?

Comment: Todo es limitado a los recursos, que n extricto rigor nunca se conectan simultáneo, siempre hay orden en cada conexión. Y el xml se guarda por cada persona en orden, la velocidad del server determina cuánta espera deberá tener cada cliente. Ojo MySQL puede soportar muchas conexiones hasta Miles si está bien configurado

Comment: @John ¿donde puedo ver mas información de conexiones simultaneas a MySQL y de buena configuración para hacer miles?

Comment: [aqui](https://shorturl.at/arvU3) en tu archivo de configuración buscas max_connections, pero hay que entender que las llamadas a la base deben ser comprendiendo las normas de programación, que es eso? pues una consulta select se hace conectando a la base haciendo la consulta y cerrando la conexión, las conexiones dependen del tu equipo, por ejemplo un ryzen 18 hilos con disco nvme te puede aguantar fácil unas 800 o 1000 conexiones simultaneas. todo esta en el equipo, su usas clusters mucho mejor.

Comment: Acceder al mismo archivo no debe representar problemas, pero si todos los usuarios pueden modificarlo, el único inconveniente es que no puedes determinar cuál es la modificación que va a prevalecer y necesitas establecer una lógica para pocesarlo. De entrada, me parece muy mala idea que tantos usuarios tengan ese privilegio, independientemente de lo que hagas con el archivo.

Comment: PHP no tiene soporte multy treathing; por ende siempre habrá una cola de conexión; si lo que buscas es ejecutar múltiples veces un script php y que este tenga acceso al mismo xml todo dependerá de la capacidad del harware(recursos) y de los recursos configurados para el servidor web.

Comment: lo que si te aseguro es que puede verse interrumpido la ejecución de php si intentas escribir en un archivo que esta bloqueado por que se esta escribiendo por otro o el mismo script php.